# Weighted median in R

Tags: r, median

I would like a suggestion on the best way on how to calculate a weighted median in R.

I have this kind of dataframe:

```
id         2       5        10
1       5408.55    0.00     0.00
10      1158.51    0.00     1006.37
100     18263.69   4205.64  0.00
20      27483.89   7601.01  833.90
```

- **id** is the sample unit
- **2, 5, 10** are categories, but also the value
  from which I want to compute the median (equal for each sample unit).

At the coloumn-row intersections there are the weighs I want to use for the weighted median.

Any suggestion on which is the best package/functions doing this operation?

Thank you

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=weighted+median

Comment: R package 'spatstat' has a weighted.median function